# How to graph a political coordinates graph

Tags: svg

I'm trying to program a graph like this one:

[image: Political Coordinates]

I tried with SVG, but it's not very good since I had to use 2 different rectangles and didn't manage to get only the 4 edges to be rounded.

Here's my code:

```
    <svg width="400" height="250">
<defs>
    <linearGradient id="solids" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
        <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
        <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
        <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,255,0);stop-opacity:1" />
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,255,0);stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="solids2" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
        <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1" />
        <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1" />
        <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,255);stop-opacity:1" />
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,255);stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
    <text x="135" y="12" style="fill:black;">Conservadorismo
    <tspan x="150" y="240">Liberalismo</tspan>
    <tspan x="20" y="125">Esquerda</tspan>
    <tspan x="305" y="125">Direita</tspan>
    </text>
    <rect x="100" y="20" rx="20" ry="20" width="200" height="100" style="fill:url(#solids); opacity:0.76" />
    <rect x="100" y="120" rx="20" ry="20" width="200" height="100" style="fill:url(#solids2); opacity:0.76" />
    <line x1="100" y1="120" x2="300" y2="120" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:2" />    
    <line x1="200" y1="20" x2="200" y2="220" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:2" />
</svg>
```

What should I do to fix it or do it better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use ordinary `<rect>` objects without rounded corners, and apply a `clipPath` to the whole drawing to round off the corners.

Here's a simple example:

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
<defs>
  <clipPath id="roundRect">
    <rect x="10" y="10" rx="20" ry="20" width="380" height="380"/>
  </clipPath>
</defs>
<g clip-path="url(#roundRect)">
  <rect fill="#0a0" stroke="none" x="10" y="10" width="190" height="190"/>
  <rect fill="#f00" stroke="none" x="200" y="10" width="190" height="190"/>
  <rect fill="#0bf" stroke="none" x="10" y="200" width="190" height="190"/>
  <rect fill="#fd0" stroke="none" x="200" y="200" width="190" height="190"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Could you please explain to me how does "viewBox" and "clipPath" work please?

Comment: The [`viewBox`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) defines the region of SVG coordinates that are mapped to the rectangular SVG viewport, and a [`clipPath`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html#EstablishingANewClippingPath) defines which parts of the underlying objects are visible. In this example, the clip path is a rounded rectangle, and by applying it to the `<g>` element containing the coloured squares, it has the effect of cutting off the outer corners. I suggest you add your grid lines inside the same `<g>` element so they are also clipped at the corners.